# Python cause of "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'readline'"

Tags: python, readline, attributeerror, try-except

I'm trying to print integers from a file where each line has 1 integer, as well as print their sum. Everything seems to work fine, except when I enter the incorrect file name, loop back, and then enter the correct one. The program still outputs the correct information but then the error:
"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'readline'". Why is this happening?

```
def main():
    listnums = filetolist()
    print(f'numbers in file: {listnums}')
    print(f' sum of before mentioned numbers is: {sum(listnums)}')


# opens file
def openfile():
    try:
        file = open(input("what is the file named including the file extension?"), "r")
        return file
    except IOError:
        tryagain = input("File could not be found \n" + "if you would like try again type 1 and press enter, to exit press enter")
        if tryagain == "1":
            main()
        else:
            exit()


# converts file to list
def filetolist():
    file = openfile()
    line = file.readline()
    nums = []
    linenumber = 1
    while line != "":
        nums += [verifyint(line, linenumber)]
        line = file.readline()
        linenumber += 1
    file.close()
    return nums


# verifies number is an int
def verifyint(num, linenumber):
    try:
        numint = int(num)
        return numint
    except ValueError:
        print(f'Invalid value on line #{linenumber}')
        exit()


main()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think (i might be wrong) that the problem is that when you fail to read a file and try again you need to recall `openfile` and not the whole `main`.
If you call the whole `main` you are opening a new file doing all the routine and then returning nothing.

Try that And tell me if it works

```
def openfile():
    try:
        file = open(input("what is the file named including the file extension?"), "r")
        return file
    except IOError:
        tryagain = input("File could not be found \n" + "if you would like try again type 1 and press enter, to exit press enter")
        if tryagain == "1":
            return openfile()
        else:
            exit()
```

here a screenshot
[image]

Comment: it's working for me. i'm going to edit the anwer to add an screenshot

Comment: using return openfile() worked, thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you hit the `except` block, there is no return statement, so this function returns `None` after running `main()` again

Rather than effectively recurse, you should properly raise the errors and use a proper loop

```
def filetolist(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return [int(line.rstrip()) for line in f]

def main():
    while True:
        filename = input("what is the file named including the file extension?")
        try:
            listnums = filetolist(filename)
            print(f'numbers in file: {listnums}')
            print(f' sum of before mentioned numbers is: {sum(listnums)}')
        except ValueError, IOError:
            again = input('Error! Try again? (y/n)')
            if again.lower() != 'y':
                break

main()
```